# Xamarin Forms Video player with local mp4

Tags: android, video, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I work on Xamarin Forms to make a page with a video player to play a local mp4 for Xamarin.Android.

So, I created a "raw" folder in my Xamarin.Droid (in Resources folder) and put my video with AndroidResource for compiler.

I use [this](https://github.com/Rod-at-Rox/RoxXamarinVideo/) plugin to display my video, because I don't want to have Controller, and I want to loop my video.

But, it said : Can't play video.

I think it's because it didn't found the video...

I don't know how I can fix it.

Thanks for your help

Comment: https://github.com/Rod-at-Rox/RoxXamarinVideo/issues/17

Comment: @Jason yup I know, but I want to know if the video folder is correct. Must I put my video in drawable, or assets or raw...? Going to try an other plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Must I put my video in drawable, or assets or raw...?

You will need to place your video in raw, and for plugin, I'm not going to suggest any third-party plugin here, you may choose by your self. I here use `Custom Renderer` to create a custom view to play local video use the official control `VideoView` of Android platform.

For example:

Create `MyVideoView` in PCL:

```
public class MyVideoView : View
{
}
```

Create its renderer in Android project:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MyVideoView), typeof(MyVideoViewRenderer))]

namespace NameSpace.Droid
{
    public class MyVideoViewRenderer : ViewRenderer
    {
        private VideoView videoview;

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.View> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            if (e?.NewElement == null || e.OldElement != null)
            {
                return;
            }

            if (Control == null)
            {
                videoview = new VideoView(Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context);
                SetNativeControl(videoview);

                videoview.SetVideoPath("android.resource://" + Android.App.Application.Context.PackageName + "/" + Resource.Raw.one);
                videoview.Start();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Since I directly give the local path to `VideoView` in renderer, you can simply use this control in xaml like this:

```
<local:MyVideoView HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
```

And because it is official `VideoView`, there're a lot of samples show how to use it together with `MediaController` if you'd like to have transport controller for  it.